# Plot a rent graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have to plot this:

[Rent plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocibJ.png)

The legend should show the current city that the rent is being plotted for, the x ticks should show the month/year, and the y tick should show one list of rent for that city

The dictionary contains zipcode and city key value pairs:

95136,San Jose

95134,San Jose

95131,San Jose

95129,San Jose

95128,San Jose

95126,San Jose

95125,San Jose

95123,San Jose

95117,San Jose

95112,San Jose

95110,San Jose

95054,Santa Clara

95051,Santa Clara

95050,Santa Clara

95035,Milpitas

95032,Los Gatos

95014,Cupertino

95008,Campbell

94306,Palo Alto

94089,Sunnyvale

94087,Sunnyvale

94085,Sunnyvale

94043,Mountain View

94040,Mountain View
And the numpy array contains lists of rents for each zipcode:

2659,2623.5,2749.5,2826.5,2775,2795,2810,2845,2827,2847,2854,2897.5,2905,2925,2902.5,2869.5

3342.5,3386,3385,3353,3300,3190,3087.5,3092,3170,3225,3340,3315,3396,3470,3480,3380

2996,2989,2953,2950,2884.5,2829,2785,2908,2850,2761,2997.5,3020,2952,2997.5,2952,2923.5

2804.5,2850.5,2850,2850,2867,2940,2905,2945,2938,2860,2884,2946,2938,2986.5,2931.5,3032.5

2800,3074,2950,2850,2850,2875,2757,2716,2738.5,2696,2809,2891,3000,2960,2950,2831

3215,3250,3290,3260,3200,3350,3507.5,3301,3276,3320,3550,3500,3530,3498.5,3505,3605

2597.5,2649,2625.5,2890,3325,3200,3010,2850,2800,2745,2695,2695,2850,2850,2860,2695

2783.5,2800,2812,2809,2813.5,2817,2815,2849,2850,2927,2810,2890,2910,2996,2950,2897

2350,2350,2350,2475,2400,2495,2567.5,2525,2400,2350,2487.5,2395,2397.5,2450,2562.5,2500

3152.5,3015,3060,3027.5,2950,3000,3002.5,3022.5,2865,2850,2825,2895,3020,3022.5,3110,3185

3337,3500,3484,3519,3393.5,3295,3062.5,3057,3123.5,3103,3079,3216,3221,3200,3214,3405.5

3180,3325,3495,3488.5,3271.5,3216,3235,3216,3300,3405,3388.5,3600,3915,3629.5,3541,3405

2800,3049,3000,3032,2995,2987.5,2850,3000,3000,2895,2992.5,3080,3378.5,3094.5,3056,3150

2871.5,2850,2751,2710,2800,2875,2845,2700,2784.5,2749,2800,2875,2905,3028,3100,3100

3552.5,3550,3540,3510,3495,3510,3512.5,3525,3300,3270,3250,3182.5,3200,3200 ,3250,3200

3397.5,3389,3450,3400,3300,3500,3495,3497.5,3395,3595,3350,3350,3425,3399.5,3364.5,3325.5

3550,3472,3493,3344.5,3332,3251,3270.5,3358,3370.5,3465.5,3495,3495,3500,3495,3458,3550

2805,2833,2900,2930,2795,2800,2890,2949,2800,2850,2839,2900,2850,2995,3087.5,2950.5

3495,3530,3610,4200,3990,3925,4000,3785,3792.5,3525,3495,3850,3900,4137.5,4000,4200

3545,3355,3305,3143,3220,3200,3180,3639,3260,3265,3510,3575,3695,3482.5,3600,3292.5

2995,3180,3225,3204,3219,3109,2998.5,2995,3200,3193.5,3161,3195,3200,3338.5,3200,3176

3599,3641,3796,3650,3552.5,3570,3535,3465,3400,3316,3640,3770,3440,3790,3815,3692.5

3500,3509.5,3519,3717.5,3495,3435,3285,3162.5,3425,3375,3410,3472.5,3600,3980,3657.5,3650

3773,3696,3708,3778,3689,3625,3516,3518.5,3647,3596,3685,3945,3811,3848,3699,4021.5
The rent array and dictionary indices should match.

I have 4 class attributes self.startMonth, self.startYear, self.endMonth, and self.endYear. I also have a function called cityPlot that takes in city, month, year parameter and I have a loop inside that searches for the city in the dictionary and a loop to find the index of the zipcode rent to search for in the numpy array.

```
def priceTrend(self, city, month, year):
    self.startMonth = month
    self.startYear = year
    count = 0
    rent = []
    cityName = ''
    for keys, cities in self.city.items():
        if self.city[keys] == city:
            cityName = self.city[cities]
            for i in self.arrRent[count]:
                rent.append(i)
                self.startMonth += 1
    plt.plot(self.startMonth, rent, lable=cityName)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.show()
```

I'm brand new to numpy and plotting so I am not really sure how to do the plotting. I am getting errors when plotting and im not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it would be much better if you use pandas to import data files so that you can easily convert them to numpy arrays whenever you need them.
Then you can do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%inline matplotlib
pin = ['12345','12346','12347','12348','12349','12340']
rent = [1000,2000,800,1600,900,1200]
plt.plot(pin,rent)
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the output according to the array i have considered above]